# Is it possible to change from domains to phrases in the URL bar?

Tags: url, javascript, browsers

You can change a URL like `google.com` to `google.com/test` without reloading the page by JavaScript.

Is it possible to completely change the URL like from `google.com` to `Welcom.To.The.Website` using the URL bar as a display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to completely change the url like from google.com to Welcom.To.The.Website

No, you cannot change the domain (ie. the *origin*). Presumably you are referring to HTML5's `pushState()`? From [Mozilla Developer help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception.

Apart from being confusing for users. This would also be a security issue. Pretending to be a site you are not - phishing. A website could also trick you into visiting another malicious website just by hitting the back button.